# Block like surface when painting bump map

Tags: texture-painting

So I painted bump map started with grey color with rgb values .5, and I painted with not full black color and I decreased strength to ~.15 when I took a look of what object look with bump map, it was ugly as I have low resolution image I tried all sizes for 1k to 4k and they give me same results, I tried saving as 16 bit it gave same results, tried plugging it in displacement input still no difference, how to overcome/fix this so it becomes smooth, and yes node is set to non color data.

p.s. on images strength of bump map is decreased to ~.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check node's interpolation type: should be Linear or Cubic

Comment: Well, that was on linear, as it comes by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a new bump texture image, be sure to tick the option 'Float Buffer' so that you use 32 bit instead of 8 bit or 16 bit image depth.
[image]

Comment: Wow, I thought it was brainfart because I couldn't find 32 bit option and I heard people talking about it, thanks!